# WooCommerce изменить данные пользователя

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Прошу подсказать, как изменить личные данные пользователя для WooCommerce.
Пробую:

```
$user_id = 1;
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
$customer->set_billing_address( 'address_1' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел исходники. Эта функция добавляет данные в объект в памяти. Для сохранения в базу попробуйте так:

```
$user_id = 1;
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
$customer->set_billing_address( 'address_1' );
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Да, сохраняется, спасибо!